# how can i call optbinning module get results of all varible binning

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, binning

Now i use optbinning module to binning all logstic regression modeling varible. 
however optbinning module need to use only one variable ,such as

```
variable = "REGION_POPULATION_RELATIVE"
x = df[variable].values
y = df.TARGET.values
from optbinning import OptimalBinning
optb = OptimalBinning(name=variable, dtype="numerical", solver="ls", max_n_prebins=100,
                      min_prebin_size=0.001, time_limit=50)
optb.fit(x, y)
```

how can i use loop to get binning result for all variable ?
i try to codeing

```
variable_names = train_validation_valid_nonstring_nondatetype_categoryencoders.keys()
for i in variable_names:
    optb = OptimalBinning(name=i,dtype="numerical", solver="cp")
    optb.fit(x_category_encoders_target, y_category_encoders)
```

but get error "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (52803,602) (52803,) "
i get dataframe including hundreds variable, it will be a huge project if one by one calculation.
please help me,thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To compute the optimal binning of all variables in a dataset, you can use the BinningProcess class.

- tutorials:http://gnpalencia.org/optbinning/tutorials/tutorial_binning_process_telco_churn.html
- documentation: http://gnpalencia.org/optbinning/binning_process.html

```py
from optbinning import BinningProcess

binning_process = BinningProcess(variable_names=variable_names)
binning_process.fit(df[variable_names], df[target])
```

Then, you can retrieve information for each variable or a given list of variables using method `get_binned_variable`. For example:

```py
for variable in variable_names:
    optb = binning_process.get_binned_variable(name=variable)
    optb.binning_table.build()
    optb.binning_table.plot()
    optb.binning_table.analysis()
```

Comment: Please avoid posting links as solutions. Those links could die over time. It is better to post a reproducible solution directly in the answer.

Comment: Good to know about this package. Will try to use it for my problem. However, I have a quick question. when most of the posts here in this forum advice against binning continuous variables, can I check with you on why do you think/how this binning will be useful? As you are the creator of this package, I feel it would be useful to know your views on this.